# working with webcam asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webcam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to capture image from client webcam in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321246/how-to-capture-image-from-client-webcam-in-asp-net)

Hi i want to capture a video using asp.net c# webapplication. How can i do it?

(Just like recording video in facebook)

Can you have any examples plz help me.

I've gone through google but nothing is suitable for me

Answer (score 3):

Not really much to go on is there... 
I am assuming you want a user to be able to record video in your app. This is not possible without a plugin on the user's machine, like Flash, because it means accessing hardware on the client machine. Flash has this built in and will ask for it to be allowed to access the user's webcam.

You might want to bwe a bit more clear with your question though...

Answer (score 2):

Use Microsoft Expression Encoder for broadcast, and simple Silverlight of Flash control for presentation on a client side.