# capture webcam using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, webcam

I want to capture webcam image in ASP.NET C#. I have searched in Google, but i get code only for windows application. I'm not getting solution for web application.
please help me guys..

Comment: Are you using HTML5? Else you should look into flash or silverlight applications.

Comment: no.. I'm not using html5. I don't have knowledge in Flash or silver-light. so please guide me to solve it easy.

Comment: I hope you are not planning to spy after someones computer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture image from client webcam in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321246/how-to-capture-image-from-client-webcam-in-asp-net)

Comment: Check http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

Comment: "so please guide me to solve it easy"

Answer (score 1):

you will have to use a plugin in case you are not using HTML5..
the plugin or html5 will take the image and upload it to the server..
there can be **no direct way** in which you asp.net server(IIS) can diorectly interact with the webcam

Answer (score 1):

This is not at all possible with C#/ASP.net as this is code that runs on the server, NOT on the client's computer which is where the webcam resides.

**You will need a client-side solution for this.**

The current standings of HTML5 and webcams are very scarce, and no-one seems to have properly implemented it:
http://caniuse.com/#search=webcam

I would recommend silverlight or flash (I'm going to swing towards flash as it has a stronger user base - but saying that, if SL is quicker/cleaner to dev, and you tell your users they need SL - it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same techniques as in a Windows application, but it will use the camera on the server... You need to access the user's camera from its browser, which is tricky. Here's a similar question about HTML5 : [How to access webcam from HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074230/how-to-access-webcam-from-html5)

Comment: And HTML5 doesn't yet support Webcams - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318834/whats-the-status-of-the-html-5-video-tag-and-webcam-integration